# Why am I getting NameError in MacOSX Terminal?

Tags: python, macos

I am a trying to run a Choose your own adventure type game in Mac terminal but I am getting this error when inputting the first answer.

```
answer = input("Would you like to play?  (yes/no): ")

if answer.lower().strip() == "yes":

    answer = input("You reach a crossroad, what will you do?").lower().strip()

else:
    print("That's too bad")




Would you like to play?  (yes/no): yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cyoa.py", line 1, in <module>
    answer = input("Would you like to play?  (yes/no): ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `python3` instead.

Comment: If you must use Python 2 then you should use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to get strings from user input, `input()` in Python 2 will try to evaluate the user's input